# Is it possible to decrypt this message with partially known data?

Tags: encryption

The following highlighted text must contains `547a5e0e008be33730158d63ce844e67` data. I don't know about encryption method and key.

Is it possible to decrypt it?

[image: Screenshot of hexdump]

Or just give me some idea about encryption method that they use to encrypt it.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what encryption method was used from seeing a few bytes. If you're trying to do reverse engineering, you're doing it wrong. You need to either look at a lot of data with the same structure (preferably data that you injected into the system), or better, run the program that produced the data in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The first 32 bytes seem to be the ASCII representation of a 16-byte hexadecimal string. Possibly an Initialization Vector (IV) or similar. That would leave us with 88 bytes remaining. My guess is that this encryption is made by some 128-bit block cipher (e.g., AES-128), using some mode of operation such as CTR or CBC. Note that 88 bytes is not a valid ciphertext size when using AES-128 and CBC mode, but maybe there are 8 bytes that are not part of the ciphertext.

It would be nice if you provide a textual version of the highlighted hexadecimal data.